# Twitter API Rate Limit - Overcoming on an unauthenticated JSON Get with Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, oauth, twitter

I see the rate limit is 150/hr per IP. This'd be fine, but my application is on a mobile phone network (with shared IP addresses).

I'd like to query twitter trends, e.g. GET /trends/1/json. 
This doesn't require authorization, however what if the user first authorized with my application using OAuth, then hit the JSON API?

The request is built as follows:

```
- (void) queryTrends:(NSString *) WOEID {

 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/%@.json", WOEID];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
            timeoutInterval:10.0];


 NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
 if (theConnection) {
  // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
  theData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
 } else {
  NSLog(@"Connection failed in Query Trends");
 }

 //NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];


}
```

I have no idea how I'd build this request as an authenticated one however, and haven't seen any examples to this effect online.

I've read through the twitter OAuth documentation, but I'm still puzzled as to how it should work. 
I've experimented with OAuth using Ben Gottlieb's prebuild library, and calling this in my first viewDidLoad:

```
 OAuthViewController *oAuthVC = [[OAuthViewController alloc]
       initWithNibName:@"OAuthTwitterDemoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 // [self setViewController:aViewController];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:oAuthVC animated:YES];
```

This should store all the keys required in the app's preferences, I just need to know how to build the GET request after authorizing!

Maybe this just isn't possible? Maybe I'll have to proxy the requests through a server side application?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Authorizing through OAuth will provide you an authorization token, which you need to pass to each request you make later on.

Refer to Twitter docs, read about how authorization works.

Comment: Did so again, found this:
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#auth-request
..so programatically, I'd set each of these parameters as header attributes of my above 'theRequest' GET request?

Comment: Wait, no.. whole bunch of other stuff to be calculated too. Can this be done using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine?
Found plenty of examples of how to do the initial connect with OAuth but none on how to build a request after that's been done.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of searching I've managed to figure how to construct a request to the JSON API programmatically in Xcode. 
Firstly, you need to use the OAuth demo code to authenticate and authorize your application.

Then, you'll be retrieving the key by doing: [prefs stringForKey:@"authData"] - if this doesn't exist, you haven't been OAuth'd properly.

I had to reverse engineer this by looking through the code of the OAuth library, and while it's easy to use the library for stuff like sending a status update, it doesn't allow you to retrieve trends...:

```
#import "OAMutableURLRequest.h"
#import "MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection.h"
NSMutableString *dataString;

    // Using OAuth:


OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"YOURCONSUMERKEY"
                                                secret:@"YOURCONSUMERSECRET"];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *authData = [prefs stringForKey:@"authData"];
//  [_engine 

OAMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"]
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token: (authData) ? [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:authData] : nil
                                                                      realm: nil
                                                          signatureProvider:nil] autorelease];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO]; 

// Set headers for client information, for tracking purposes at Twitter.
[theRequest setValue:@"Trendy"    forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client"];
[theRequest setValue:@"1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-Version"];
[theRequest setValue:@"http://www.inisdesign.com"     forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-URL"];

// Set the request body if this is a POST request.

[theRequest prepare];

// Create a connection using this request, with the default timeout and caching policy, 
// and appropriate Twitter request and response types for parsing and error reporting.
MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection *connection;
connection = [[MGTwitterHTTPURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                                     requestType:MGTwitterFollowedTimelineRequest // Wrong type
                                                    responseType:MGTwitterStatuses]; // as above - doesnt seem to matter


if (!connection) {
    return;
} else {
    //      [_connections setObject:connection forKey:[connection identifier]];
    //      [connection release];
    dataString = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    [connection start];
}
```

}

The rest is implemented as a standard URL connection with didReceiveData methods etc.. 
I haven't verified this is alleviating my rate limiting problems, but hey.. It's a start if anybody has similar problems.